# Rearrange data before printing

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

I currently have code that pulls data from a db, then does some math on part of it, and then prints it to a table. However, I would like to arrange the numbers printed from larges down to smallest. I'm familiar with ordering in the query, however the query doesn't know what the end result will be. What would be the most efficient way to go about rearranging this data.

```
<?php
    $hourAmount = $mlYeild * (3600 / $cycleTime);
    $oreVolumePriceQuery = "SELECT od.oreID, od.inGameID, od.size, ir.officialCorpRate FROM oreData od JOIN itemRates ir ON od.inGameID = ir.typeID order by od.oreID asc";
    $oreVolumePriceResult = mysql_query($oreVolumePriceQuery);
$hourYeild = $mlYeild * (3600 / $cycleTime);
?>
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD><h1>Ore</h1></TD>
        <TD><h1>Hourly Yeild</h1></TD>
        <TD><h1>Hourly Sale</h1></TD>
    </TR>
    <?php
        $ores = array();
        While($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($oreVolumePriceResult)){
            $inGameID = $row['inGameID'];
            $volume = $row['size'];
            $rate = $row['officialCorpRate'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $hourlyYeild = $hourAmount/$volume;
            $hourlyIncome = $hourlyYeild * $rate;

            echo "<TR>";
            echo "<TD>".$name."</TD>";
            echo "<TD>".$hourlyYeild."</TD>";
            echo "<TD>".$hourlyIncome."</TD>";
            echo "</TR>";
        }
    ?>
</TABLE>
```

in short, from the data that comes in, I would like it to be arranged via `$hourlyIncome desc`

Comment: Just a question but if you want to order by 'hourlyincome desc' why in your mysql query are you sorting by 'od.oreID asc'?

Comment: Where does $hourAmount come from?

Comment: So you want to sort an array?

Comment: @DevonBernard because hourlyincome isn't isn't in the db. If it was this would be easier

Comment: @Strawberry I accidentally a variable, I will add it in

Comment: @shapeshifter essentially yes, but i'm not entirely sure how to get the data into the array, or how to sort the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First store your computations back into the `$row` (it looked like `$hourAmount` was missing--I assumed that this was `$rate`, hope I got it right):

   `$inGameID = $row['inGameID'];

   $volume = $row['size'];

   $rate = $row['officialCorpRate'];

   $name = $row['name'];

   $hourlyYield = $row['hourlyYield'] = $rate /$volume;

   $hourlyIncome = $row['hourlyIncome '] = $hourlyYield * $rate;`
2. Append the `$row` to a `$rows` array: `$rows[] = $row;`
3. When you have all the `$rows`, use a custom comparison function to sort the `$rows` array.

   User-defined comparison:

   ```
   function cmp($a, $b)  
   {  
       if ($a['hourlyIncome'] == $b['hourlyIncome']) {  
           return 0;  
       }  
       return ($a['hourlyIncome'] < $b['hourlyIncome']) ? 1 : -1;  
   }
   ```
4. Sort `$rows` via `usort($rows, $comp);`
5. Do a standard loop over `$rows` to display.

Note:  Still seems to me like all of these calculations could have been done on the SQL side.

Comment: sweet thanks. It's entirely possibly they could all be done on the SQL side. I'm relatively new to all of this so I have no doubt that my entire site is incredibly inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if it's the most efficient way but you can store the calculated data in an array and then sort it.